# I want to have a select and input field in react with all the options in my JSON file or mongodb database

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, forms

I have to provide a dropdown in my form with a large number of options in it but the selected options are to be shown at various places so i have to store the selected option or its id at database too.

```
<FormGroup>
                  <Label htmlFor="category">Category</Label>
                   <select innerRef={input => (this.category = input)} id="select" class="form-control" >
                      <option value="0">Please select</option>
                      <option value="1">Mobiles</option>
                      <option value="2">Television</option>
                      <option value="3">Washing Machines</option>
                  </select>
</FormGroup>
```

This is the gist of the form type i want, there will be other categories in somewhere around 25. I cant have 25 options opening in dropdown. I want to have something like select and input type in dropdown. Also i want to store the option selected by the user and then display it somewhere else.

Comment: It's very unclear what you are asking. Could you include the code you have written so far?

Comment: I hope this helps. @Tholle